# Trying to recreate a feature / shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I found a picture of this website here: [image]

And I was wondering how the did the bottom wavy part between the purple and the white sections.

My first thought was to use clip-path but I'm not familiar with this too much. My second thought was to use some shapes to try and recreate this but that seems like it wouldn't be the best way to approach this problem.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to this question ecg8. Much appreciated...

Comment: What about going to the site and inspecting the markup on how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use an SVG (Scalable Vector Graphic) as a clip-path. If you make an SVG and scale it up, you can use it to clip the background with the shape of the SVG.  To get this specific design, you can use Inkscape (best free SVG editor) or Illustrator (if you can afford it) to design a shape.

Here is an example from a codepen:

```css
#shape-container {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis_big.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape-container">
  <svg width="1245px" height="780px" viewBox="0 0 1245 780" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g>
            <clipPath id="shape-top">
                <polygon points="1,95,1,0,979,0,424,379,1,95px"></polygon>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="shape-left">
                <polygon points="1,95,424,379,1,668,1,95"></polygon>
            </clipPath>
        </g>
        <image clip-path="url(#shape-top)" width="1245" height="780" xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis4_big.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"></image>
        <image clip-path="url(#shape-left)" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I'm not going to write the code for you, that is not what stack overflow is for, but I will give you an SVG path that you can use as inspiration for what can be done.  Play around with the size, and other things, and see if this helps with your request.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640">
    <defs>
        <path d="M41 604L959 604" id="b4hRkibCzL"></path>
        <path d="M-807.1 671.89L-807.1 -22.11" id="aJGvCq9Ld"></path>
        <path d="M754.04 792.17L754.04 98.17" id="a2BjBBZ1Jf"></path>
        <path d="M-21.55 256.93L-12.55 245.98L-2.55 235.04L6.45 224.59L15.45 214.14L24.45 204.19L34.45 194.74L43.45 185.78L52.45 177.32L61.45 169.86L71.45 163.39L80.45 157.42L89.45 152.45L99.45 147.97L108.45 144.99L117.45 143L126.45 142L136.45 142L145.45 143L154.45 144.99L163.45 147.97L173.45 152.45L182.45 157.42L191.45 163.39L201.45 169.86L210.45 177.32L219.45 185.78L228.45 194.74L238.45 204.19L247.45 214.14L256.45 224.59L265.45 235.04L275.45 245.98L284.45 256.93L293.45 267.87L303.45 278.82L312.45 289.27L321.45 299.72L330.45 309.67L340.45 319.12L349.45 328.08L358.45 336.53L367.45 344L377.45 350.46L386.45 356.43L395.45 361.41L405.45 365.89L414.45 368.87L423.45 370.86L432.45 371.86L442.45 371.86L451.45 370.86L460.45 368.87L469.45 365.89L479.45 361.41L488.45 356.43L497.45 350.46L507.45 344L516.45 336.53L525.45 328.08L534.45 319.12L544.45 309.67L553.45 299.72L562.45 289.27L571.45 278.82L581.45 267.87L590.45 256.93L599.45 245.98L609.45 235.04L618.45 224.59L627.45 214.14L636.45 204.19L646.45 194.74L655.45 185.78L664.45 177.32L673.45 169.86L683.45 163.39L692.45 157.42L701.45 152.45L711.45 147.97L720.45 144.99L729.45 143L738.45 142L748.45 142L757.45 143L766.45 144.99L775.45 147.97L785.45 152.45L794.45 157.42L803.45 163.39L813.45 169.86L822.45 177.32L831.45 185.78L840.45 194.74L850.45 204.19L859.45 214.14L868.45 224.59L877.45 235.04L887.45 245.98L896.45 256.93" id="c6gYkOZIbc"></path>
        <path d="M288.61 290.61C288.61 361.98 217.2 419.91 129.24 419.91C41.28 419.91 -30.13 361.98 -30.13 290.61C-30.13 219.25 41.28 161.31 129.24 161.31C217.2 161.31 288.61 219.25 288.61 290.61Z" id="dnajv2alU"></path>
        <path d="M398.83 394.81C398.83 466.17 327.41 524.11 239.45 524.11C151.49 524.11 80.08 466.17 80.08 394.81C80.08 323.45 151.49 265.51 239.45 265.51C327.41 265.51 398.83 323.45 398.83 394.81Z" id="fdGDhcwxN"></path>
        <path d="M625.71 462.92C625.71 534.29 554.3 592.22 466.34 592.22C378.38 592.22 306.96 534.29 306.96 462.92C306.96 391.56 378.38 333.62 466.34 333.62C554.3 333.62 625.71 391.56 625.71 462.92Z" id="dNZoIoCMk"></path>
        <path d="M780.42 415.56C780.42 486.93 709.01 544.87 621.05 544.87C533.09 544.87 461.68 486.93 461.68 415.56C461.68 344.2 533.09 286.26 621.05 286.26C709.01 286.26 780.42 344.2 780.42 415.56Z" id="a5PN3oIKQ"></path>
        <path d="M836.51 352.57C836.51 423.93 765.1 481.87 677.14 481.87C589.18 481.87 517.76 423.93 517.76 352.57C517.76 281.21 589.18 223.27 677.14 223.27C765.1 223.27 836.51 281.21 836.51 352.57Z" id="mmmdIctph"></path>
        <path d="M749.52 572.29C749.52 643.65 547.41 701.59 298.47 701.59C49.52 701.59 -152.59 643.65 -152.59 572.29C-152.59 500.92 49.52 442.98 298.47 442.98C547.41 442.98 749.52 500.92 749.52 572.29Z" id="d5EhBzC2WL"></path>
        <path d="M561.37 455.12C561.37 526.48 359.26 584.42 110.32 584.42C-138.63 584.42 -340.74 526.48 -340.74 455.12C-340.74 383.75 -138.63 325.81 110.32 325.81C359.26 325.81 561.37 383.75 561.37 455.12Z" id="b4ZW7wUE7Y"></path>
        <path d="M970.02 262.36C970.02 333.72 898.61 391.66 810.65 391.66C722.69 391.66 651.27 333.72 651.27 262.36C651.27 191 722.69 133.06 810.65 133.06C898.61 133.06 970.02 191 970.02 262.36Z" id="ev4URzEBW"></path>
        <path d="M856.51 372.57C856.51 443.93 785.1 501.87 697.14 501.87C609.18 501.87 537.76 443.93 537.76 372.57C537.76 301.21 609.18 243.27 697.14 243.27C785.1 243.27 856.51 301.21 856.51 372.57Z" id="elqPiiaJT"></path>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#b4hRkibCzL" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#b4hRkibCzL" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#7f7f7f" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#aJGvCq9Ld" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#aJGvCq9Ld" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#7f7f7f" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#a2BjBBZ1Jf" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#a2BjBBZ1Jf" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#7f7f7f" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <path></path>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#c6gYkOZIbc" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#c6gYkOZIbc" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="80" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#dnajv2alU" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#dnajv2alU" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#fdGDhcwxN" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#fdGDhcwxN" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#dNZoIoCMk" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#dNZoIoCMk" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#a5PN3oIKQ" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#a5PN3oIKQ" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#mmmdIctph" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#mmmdIctph" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#d5EhBzC2WL" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#d5EhBzC2WL" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#b4ZW7wUE7Y" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#b4ZW7wUE7Y" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#ev4URzEBW" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#ev4URzEBW" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#elqPiiaJT" opacity="1" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#elqPiiaJT" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is an [svg editor online](https://vectr.com/) and a [clip-path generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Links: [Examples](https://coderwall.com/p/blx8kw/svg-clippath-images), [`<clipPath>` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), [Article](https://medium.com/@drewisthe/using-making-sense-of-clip-path-cf651676438c), [Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/), [Inkscape tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEjlKhVnJgU)

Comment: Hmm I don't think this answers my question though. How would you use clip-path to curve a shape to how they have it in the picture I have above?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements to achieve something like this (possibly).

Check out the below snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(190, 0, 0);
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div:before {
  width: 60%;
  left: 0;
}

div:after {
  width: 40%;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```